# Bad question warning

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Every time I post, I see the warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Only two of my 19 questions have ever ended up in a negative score. I believe one of them is actually a legitimate question, and I don't see how to edit it to make it better; even if I did, it is old and unlikely that people would vote it up so that it's no longer negative. As for the other, I acknowledge that it perhaps wasn't a great question for the site, and don't see how to edit it to make it so, so I would delete it - except that "Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking." So it's a bit of a catch-22.

Comment: Deleted Questions also have a negative impact to the site's "confidence" in you. Do you have a few of those as well?

Comment: You have 6 deleted questions - all zero or negatively scored. It's these that are counting against you.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, the first answer already mentioned that. It's a little bizarre that I can't see the questions I myself deleted without a moderator linking to them.

Comment: @user2258552 Jeff enjoys being able to delete your posts without you noticing - so you can't complain. Not sure why this includes posts deleted by yourself though.

Comment: Yeah, that really makes no sense, because all of them were deleted by me. Not to mention the fact that I still have the power to undelete them - just not to find them easily. I don't really care, but it's just about the least logical UI decision I have ever encountered.

Comment: Why do I have the power to undelete them?

Comment: Delete a Question tag i did minutes before. First i have used two tags. "regEx" and "PCRE". Then just a few minutes "regEx", because later I only use "regEx". But because the solutions also work for "PCRE", I've added "PCRE" again. But now I get this warning again "past questions have not been well-received". So repairing is delicate. But if you ask something new and you are interested in a few others, you will lose that status again (my experience). So edit later seems dangerous. Maybe better to mention bugs only in the comments but not in the question itself.

Comment: I've just had that, and deleted some messages with 0 answers. Question is, will it "follow me for the rest of my life?". Meaning, 1-2 more mistakes, and i won't be able to ask questions once again?. Today I understand a little better how things works, but at first, didn't know all of that.

Comment: It's unfortunate, because it prevents some inquisitive, well-intentioned users from posting any questions since their previous questions may have simply been unpopular.

Answer (score 29):

You have 25 questions, not 19:

- [Django tutorial problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884817/django-tutorial-problems)
- [REST API delivering ics file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932016/rest-api-delivering-ics-file)
- [Gromacs command Not found (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416099/gromacs-command-not-found-mac-os-x)
- [Practical Definition of Turning Completeness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551173/practical-definition-of-turing-completeness)
- [Is there a way to make suggestions for Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032918/is-there-a-way-to-make-suggestions-for-java-9)
- [Re-opening a File in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069854/reopening-a-file-in-c)

As far as improving your questions, you should take a look at what that link says. Also, keep in mind these points:

- Upvoted questions generally are questions that address an actual problem the OP has, not some sort of hand-wavy curiosity
- Failing #1, the curiosity is such that it's a widespread curiosity that is in some way unique.
- They are well written, with research shown and a small reproduction of the issue (Not a wall of code)

As Brad Larson says in the comments:

> And among the deleted questions, four of them were downvoted. The system's giving you a little heads-up that you're edging towards a question ban.

He's right.  You are drifting towards 'ban' territory.

Stack Overflow is not (and should not be) your first stop for every question you have about programming. I realize that's counter intuitive, but research and taking the time to fully figure out an issue before posting a question is the best way for the 'every day' learning programmer to do well on this site.

Comment: And among the deleted questions, four of them were downvoted. The system's giving you a little heads-up that you're edging towards a question ban.

Comment: Oh. How do I see my deleted questions? (Well, I can now, obviously, but how did you do it?)

Anyway, shouldn't there be some sort of statute of limitations on this penalty?

Comment: StackOverflow is my first stop for any question I have that a few hours of googling (and hacking, if applicable) doesn't resolve, simply because there is no other site (or no other site on which people actually respond). Besides the last question, which was stupid.

Comment: Also, the community responds inconsistently to some types of questions. For instance, mine was closed, but many highly upvoted questions are about Turing-Completeness (often with far fewer details than mine), so I assumed it was "okay" to ask.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker

Because people change? I am approximately 8% older and 50% more mature than I was when I asked those questions.

Comment: Lol, practical definition of "Turning" completeness: when you have gone all the way around 360 degrees of course.

Comment: "Upvoted questions generally are questions that address an actual problem the OP has, not some sort of hand-wavy curiosity" That's not my experience. Questions coming from curiosity are usually better that questions about actual problems.

Comment: I see this message on stackoverflow. When I stop getting this message. I mean when I am out of this danger zone?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what your question (or even request, perhaps) should be, is whether these bad questions in the past are going to generate warnings forever. I assume there is some mechanism on SO which makes these sort of things expire, because I've seen high-rep users with some terrible questions in their past.

I do not know how this works at the moment, but IMO - SO should issue these warnings only if there is a trend of poor questions in the last X questions you have asked. If you have some old, bad questions, but in the meantime you have posted many good ones as well, and your rep has increased, those bad questions should be considered less significant. It's normal that at the beginning users have non-perfect questions, but that should not be held against them forever.

I suspect the system already incorporates something that works as I described, as I have seen high-rep users with terrible old questions. Perhaps you have to wait a bit and just be extra careful about the questions you ask, for the time being..

Comment: Anna [wrote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179087/warn-new-users-when-they-ask-a-question-after-a-previous-question-is-closed-dow/231118#231118) that the warning applies to *"folks who are nearing hitting a block"*. So I'd *assume* the warning would no longer be shown after posting a few good questions and the chances of getting blocked have vanished, but would show as long as one is close to being banned.