# It's hard to get out of a question ban on Stack Overflow - can that be fixed?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

#### [What is a question ban?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Questions bans are triggered by automatic filters by many low-quality questions. The exact formula is secret, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of bad posts.

---

#### Users who are banned are shown [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) for getting out:

> The only way to end a question block is to positively contribute to the site... Begin by fixing your existing questions; do not just post the same question again. All questions are expected to be useful to future visitors, too, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily.

Essentially this advice is to change the community's decision, by editing the question and reversing the downvotes / getting upvotes.

This has a few issues:

1. If the question is in a low volume tag, few people will see it. If it's in a high volume tag, it will be swamped
2. Not many people sit on the "Active Questions" page - they sit on the new questions page to answer questions.
3. If the *question topic* is "meh", the community isn't going to upvote. They might not downvote, but they are unlikely to upvote. This could happen to a new user asking basic questions. If they're not interesting, they don't get upvoted. Maybe my experience is bad, but I find that new questions are normally not upvoted.

   Of the 11,098,017 questions, [5,211,136 have a score of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq%20score%3A0).
4. Any deleted questions are even worse. Close to nobody is going to see a deleted post, and why would they want to vote to undelete? It can't be voted on, and the OP can do nothing about them.

It could be that this is just the way it works, and should work - maybe users should have to work hard to get out of a ban. But there seems to be very little that can be done - even if someone *wants* to try hard and contribute.

---

So this question is here because I don't have the answers. I'd love to have the [5 sections of a feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272607/can-we-talk-about-the-voting-culture-here-on-meta/272617#272617) in my mind, but I don't.

#### So what (if anything) can be done to help users who are trying to get out? Or should nothing be done?

Comment: AFAIK, the most effort goes towards warning posters before they get banned.  If they ignore those warnings, and continue to post bad questions, and get banned, what is the point of making a huge effort to get them unbanned?  They will likely just post rubbish again:(

Comment: I know here is an 'unfairness' issue.  The good users don't get banned anyway and the worst users just use a script to keep a cache of new accounts to use up as one-account-per-question.  In between, there's a set of bad users that do get worse than they probably deserve, overall:(

Comment: Just a note: A score of 0 doesn't necessarily mean there were 0 votes.

Comment: @MartinJames Hmm, what do you mean by warnings? Sometimes, there is little that *can* be done?

Comment: Users get warnings that they can be banned before it actually happens, so it doesn't come out of nowhere.

Comment: @BSMP I'm interested in what these warnings look like?

Comment: That's not broken.

Comment: Worrying about "fairness" is kinda pointless, @Martin: near as I can tell, the "worst users" don't give a crap about anything here anyway; fairness has no meaning to them whatsoever. You might as well worry that we're being less fair toward the folks spamming inbox recovery tools than we are toward the folks spamming mystical love advice. We should always strive to engineer these systems for the benefit of the folks who actually care about the site, not to met out justice for those that don't.

Comment: If you search Meta for posts on bans, I'm sure you'll find one with the actual text and/or a screenshot of the warning.

Comment: @BSMP I have been looking at meta. I've looked through a large number of posts and haven't seen any screenshots of the fabled warning. If you can find them, please correct me!

Comment: @Tim ONE WORD "warning" in the meta search. First link : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259979/bad-question-warning

Comment: @Patrice Ta, that's what I was after. Didn't think to search for just "warning".

Comment: @Shog9 - I didn't imply that anything could be done about it, or that SO had been less than diligent.  Shit happens:(

Comment: My account is banned from asking because I asked a lot of beginner questions more aimed at assistance with debugging. Unfortunately, I was never warned ahead of time and have to make a new account now. :( I understand some people may never learn to improve my questions but I was only 10 or 11 years old and have grown significantly as a programmer since then.

Comment: If you want to reduce the number of bans, request downvoters to state a legitimate reason. Voters can stay anonymous. I have been banned twice, right after I questioned the lack of value in downvoting without an apparent cause. I cannot correct what I see as a legitimate question. I received one of those bans at the same time as I got an award for best answers. I have been programming for over 25 years. I am self-taught and not that sophisticated but I have major clients I have retained for a number of years who are very happy with the products they receive, done with meticulous attention.

Answer (score 40):

First, let's get something out of the way: it's really uncommon for folks to get out of question bans **[because most folks don't even try](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172300/what-happens-to-folks-who-get-question-banned-by-and-large)**.

[image]

Editing your crappy questions to be less awful isn't a *guarantee* of getting the ban lifted, but it's a lot, LOT more effective than doing... Nothing. All this hand-wringing about wasted effort is kinda pointless when the *vast* majority of people hitting these bans don't put in any effort whatsoever.

...That said, there **are** actually other ways of getting out of a post ban:

- **Answering questions.** spending time trying to understand other people's problems is a great way of learning how to formulate your own questions properly. And if you learn to answer *usefully*, the system will take that into account when deciding if you're still banned.
- **Editing *other people's* questions.** It can be hard to see the opportunities for improvement when looking at your own work, but sometimes editing others' writing can present a mirror by which you can learn to see the potential in your own posts. And again, if your edits are worthwhile, the system will credit you for doing *something* useful on the site when it comes time to decide if you're still banned.

Now, it can take a long, long time to work your way out of a ban by answering or editing. There was one guy I watched who spent months - the better part of a year - doing it. But he *was* successful in the end, and went on to post many questions and answers and earn many privileges.

Truth is, if all you've ever done is *ask questions* it can be awful hard to see how your work looks to the folks who are trying to answer them. Spending time learning to see the site from a new perspective can benefit you greatly - even long after the ban has been lifted.

Comment: As usual your answer is much superior compared with mine :-) ...

Comment: I liked yours, but I can't miss a chance to cross-link to some ancient post of my own.

Comment: And the illustration is really great of course :-).

Comment: there's also an option to remove account and restart at a rate of one question a week, [as explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230899/165773)

Comment: @Shog9, thank you for a definitive and informative answer. Now, how about adding this information to the advice page for question-banned? It says "Begin by fixing your existing questions", but never gets to "Continue with...". How about "In the event that fixing existing questions is not sufficient, you can improve your chances by contributing well-received answers and improving other people's questions."

Comment: The amount of work involved there is non-trivial, @Arkadiy. We used to give this advice out when folks emailed us; very, *very* few people who've hit the quality-ban have it in them to invest the sort of time and attention needed to achieve good results that way, but it invariably became a distraction (so, they'd post mediocre answers instead of editing and then email us back wondering why nothing happened). And truth is, the guidance is probably already too long.

Comment: The example reads like a partly wrong interpretation of what happened... *"There was one guy I watched who spent months - the better part of a year - doing it"* - help sections says: *"you'll get the chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions"* so the chance to ask a question after *"the better part of a year"* was likely not even the result of all the effort. Just the effort helped to fulfill the side condition of being positively received by the community.

Comment: Hi @grek40; I've been working with folks who've hit the ban for over 6 years now - the example I gave was from probably 4-5 years back now. The "you get one question every 6 months even if banned" logic is about 20 months old; prior to that, it was entirely possible to go years without being able to ask a question. Even now, if the question you ask at 6 months isn't well-received you're certainly not going to go on to ask "many questions".

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I just recently started reading about the question ban topic because someone had unaccepted my answer and completely changed the question, which turned out to be his work-around-attempt on a question ban :)

Answer (score 14):

It's intentional that it's hard getting out of a question ban and there's actually nothing needed to *fix* that.

We're already struggling a lot to keep VLQ questions out from here, and users that got question banned are most of the time unlikely to change their behavior.

They've been warned already by getting down votes or close votes long time before a ban is actually applied. So what?

> **So what (if anything) can be done to help users who are trying to get out?**

[We've already done our duty.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

> **Or should nothing be done?**

Exactly.

Comment: That link attached is unhelpful at best and harmful at worst. It says edit, and nobody sees edits. The other issue is it plants the idea of a second account in someone's mind. BRB, getting a new email address...

Comment: @Tim editing a question bumps it at the top of "new" issues, so if you edit it in shape, it'll be upvoted

Comment: @Patrice I disagree that editing my basic questions to have good grammar (they do already) will help. Personally, my issue is that I have on topic questions that are boring. Nobody upvotes them, and then I post a few truly terrible ones which are removed and I can't do anything about. There's not much I can do to make a boring question get upvotes.

Comment: @Tim I was not saying it's USEFUL, I was speaking to your point about "no one sees them". Edits are seen.

Comment: @Patrice Sure they're bumped. That doesn't make them seen. Do you sit on the active page, and do you think most people do? I don't

Comment: @Tim Do I sit on the active page? In my favorite tags... yes, actually. I have a browser page opened to it and I look at it periodically

Comment: @Tim another thing you can try is [editing other people's questions that you've answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190316/print-the-ascii-value-of-the-enter-key/33190381#33190381), given that you've already got a bunch of answers. That will get some new eyeballs on your posts; edited posts appear on the front page as well for those who are interested in the attached tags.