# What to do when I'm about to get question banned?

Tags: support, post-ban, accounts

I saw a text when I was about to ask a question that warned me from getting blocked. I've been blocked before but I don't know why. I didn't know what to do so I created this account. Here, again, I am about to get banned. I revised my previous posts but I only found 2 questions with negative reputations.

I did revise them but didn't still edit them because I don't think that will be of any benefit as there are no users following those questions, and one is closed.

I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: You get banned from posting answers for various reasons. When you only ask, and help nobody, this can ocurr.. If you have too many questions/answers with negative reputation too...

Comment: *When you only ask, and help nobody, this can occur.* This is blatantly false, @Fusseldieb. As long as you ask good questions, you're perfectly fine even with zero answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Oh, I don't knew that. Once I experienced this, and I though it came from that (Long long ago, with my first account).

Comment: "I didn't know what to do so I created this account." Creating new accounts is not a good way to get around a ban.

Comment: *What to do when I'm about to get banned?* The same thing you should do [if you do get banned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

Comment: @DavidPostill, It may not be a "good" (ie, the intended) way, but it is an effective way to get around a ban. My first account was also banned, so I opened a new one. However, if one does not want the new account to get banned, too, one has to follow the advice Oded gave below.

Comment: @DavidPostill Then what is the best way to get around a ban? We've done this about 3 times and it works perfectly

Comment: @MDXF [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584) tells you **why** you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @MDXF: _"Then what is the best way to get around a ban?"_ There is no good way to get around a ban. Ban evasion is never acceptable. If you're banned from posting it's because we don't want you posting; not because we want you to spend some time finding new and inventive ways of getting around a ban. This should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I've seen many posts that are exactly the same as this meta post, but all of them got a bunch of downvotes. Weird how this one didn't

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier it would be nice if you elaborate on that. :)

Comment: @Suragch reported.  You won't be permitted to ask more than one question per week until you have shown evidence you can ask quality questions now.

Comment: @DavidPostill I have to disagree, creating new accounts is a great and effective way for help vampires to get around a ban. Of course it's only good for the help vampire and very bad for the site, but it's not like most of the affected users care about that. And as is obvious from anecdotical evidence around meta (see OP and MD XF in this question alone) the potential penalties outlined in the faq post are usually not applied. I'd guess that's because it's hard to correlate accounts to people and SE doesn't want to punish false positives.

Comment: @AbAppletic That's because [most people who complain about question/answer bans on Meta don't even try improving or care about the warnings one gets just before getting banned](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317186). In this case, the user at least noticed the "Hey, you're about to get banned" warning.

Comment: @Yakk that's smart, but did you check that [Suragch is Top 0.02% user](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2016-01-01/3681880#3681880)? I would assume being Top 0.02% and the account being *2 years and 5 months old* means he's probably figured it out by now? Then again, you're high rank too. This whole quarrel is weird.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So, to be clear, you are stating that Suragch has "shown evidence they can ask quality questions now"?  I don't want any misunderstandings.  That would be a farce.

Comment: @Yakk ...most of them seem to be *very general* questions that he himself provides an answer to, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/2413303). I think I'm the one who should have done my research and should stay out of this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you get banned from posting how are you ever going to learn how to ask good questions? The only real way to post again is by creating a new account

Comment: @MDXF: We don't want you to post again if you repeatedly ignored the site rules for a duration of time sufficient to trigger a question ban. You should have learnt after the first slew of downvotes - preferably before! A question ban is really the last resort to deal with someone who just isn't getting it; there are _plenty_ of indications beforehand that you need to change your posting behaviour. :)

Comment: Want to get upvotes on your question? Start a bounty on it. I'm not kidding. One of my questions once went from -3 to +4

Comment: @Yakk Your response strikes me as petty (unless you were joking, in which case you got me!). Suragch has clearly demonstrated they're providing value to the community. Rate limiting a user for something they did years ago, despite providing immense value to the site since the offense, just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @cowthulhu are you asking me if Sufian has demonstrated evidence that he can ask quality questions?

Comment: @Yakk I don't need to as you - his reputation in the community (and upvotes on his questions) demonstrate that. Which is why I find it so petty that you've unilaterally decided that he his 126k rep combined with >50% rate of getting 2+ upvotes on questions (not to mention all the answers he's provided!) are insufficient to rule him a 'constructive user'.
Heck, if that doesn't make him a 'constructive user', I don't know what does. You likely know something I don't, but I hope you understand that from my perspective, it just doesn't seem justified.

Comment: @Yakk I guess to rephrase - assuming SE is as democratic as I have been led to believe it is, a high-rep user with decent performing questions is by definition asking constructive questions, as their questions would be close-voted or similar if not. Am I wrong in this assessment?

Comment: @cowthulhu If I say "X until Y occurs", and Y has already occurred, how long does X apply?

Comment: @Yakk Ahh, you were being sarcastic. My bad, it's difficult to tell when people are being sarcastic over the Internet.

Comment: @Yakk You know, I think I should apologize - I definitely was a bit overly confrontational, which was not reasonable of me. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Before asking a question, make sure you follow the [asking a good question guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Asking a good question takes effort - make sure you make that effort. Make sure your question doesn't *already* have an answer on the site.

If you do follow the guidelines, you should be fine, as the question should be of high quality and should gain upvotes.

Comment: So, I won't be asking good questions to get out of the "warning zone" but rather not to get banned?

Comment: @mzcoxfde What's the difference?

Comment: @Oded To get out (of the warning zone) and not to get in deeper.

Comment: @mzcoxfde well, they're kinda one and the same. The "ban" you're getting close to is really just a throttle that gets more and more strict, increasing the delay between being able to ask questions by as much as 6 months. It starts out at 90 minutes and adjusts based on the quality of the questions you ask and your other contributions.

Comment: Why not just post high quality questions for the sake of it? This way you will get everything you want (not banned, no warning, extra rep, more answers on your questions, all the goodies!).

Comment: Usually a high quality question tend to have less answers. *So beautiful for a dirty hand to touch*.

Comment: @Enzokie wrong! Those questions are not answered because they are too tough, others haven't explored the domain (to be able to answer it) or just because they were posted at a time when possible answerers weren't online. The "high quality" questions being referred here are those which are clear, nicely formatted and shows that you aren't looking for a freelancer.

Comment: @Sufian yeah. [Like this one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948135/how-to-write-a-switch-statement-in-ruby)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Look at how old the question is. Its from '09. SO has changed much since then.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub the opposite doesn't have to be true. And as Polygnome has said, SO has gone through a lot of change since 2009. I expect a high-rep user, like yourself, to know better than that. :P